# How to reach and show a picture which is inside a Seagate Gigabit Ethernet BlackArmor Disk with vb6

Tags: vb6, image, ethernet, network-drive

Actually i have no idea how this kinda disks works. Its the first time i deal with such disk. I putted some pictures in a folder named as oldpics and with a vb code i wanna reach it but some how i just cant find the picture inside it and its imposible cause i know that the picture is in that folder.

```
'This A_PicRoad is = "\\198.162.1.20\oldpics\" which is exist for sure
If mdiMain.fsoexist.FileExists(mdiMain.A_PicRoad & stock & ".jpg") Then

    pic1.Picture = LoadPicture(mdiMain.A_PicRoad & stock & ".jpg")

    Set img = New ImageFile
    img.LoadFile mdiMain.A_PicRoad & stok & ".jpg" 

End If
'But somehow cant find the picture and leaving this if statement without processing anything..
```

so what could be causing that?

**Edit:** I just remember that at first i must enter a username and pass while reaching `\\198.162.1.20\` after that i can reach `\\198.162.1.20\oldpics\`..

Comment: actually im sure that the code works fine it must be the part where im trying to reach the disk it needs some sort of permission that im not aware of.. I already given a lot of permissions but i guess im forgetting something that must be why i cant reach it. Is there anyone ever tried using network disks and arrange their folder permissions? Esspecially Seagate BlackArmor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a normal SMB network share, then you must use a full valued UNC path (Note the preceding `\\`)

```
\\198.162.1.20\oldpics\
```

You can also map a drive and access it via a drive letter.

Comment: Peh.. found it! Its about permissions of this damned disk.. I just had to create a "group permission" and add the users that i want to reach that folder, into that group permissions. Why such a long term configuration required for a network disk? I dont know seemed just so unnecessary to me.. As an option, group permissions would be nice but making it a requirement just causes pain in the ... or im just not yet familiar enough to these kind of disks...

Comment: The very first thing you should test before code debugging is "Does it work in Explorer"

Comment: i was hoping to find a way to reach the folder without giving "Change Folder" ability to everyone group. i thought there may be a way to enter that user name and password while logging into that folder but i do not know that! so thats why i brought this question up here.

Comment: If your app is runnign with the same priviliges/same user as Explorer, then they should be using exactly the same credentials. Windows gets all upset when you try and use multiple credentials to the same server.

Comment: i see.. so i should define each of the win users "that i'll give change permission" into the disk users with their exact name and pass. Considering that some of these users usually changes their pass i should keep those users in the disk updated which creates another pain in the ... for me but solves the situation thanks.